# Wordpress Admin Tooltip hooks

Tags: hooks, admin-menu

I want to know if there is a way to use Wordpress Adminitration Tooltips (de gray and blue ones) that are shown one you update your worpdress (3.x). Showing the new features.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simplest implementation I know of since there is no real API:

```
//add the needed scripts and styles
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_46028_enqueue_admin_scripts');
function wpse_46028_enqueue_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-pointer');
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-pointer');
    //hook the pointer 
    add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts', 'wpse_46028_print_footer_scripts' );
}
function wpse_46028_print_footer_scripts() {
    $pointer_content = '<h3>WordPress Answers</h3>';
    $pointer_content .= '<p>This is your pointer content</p>';
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    //jQuery selector to point to 
    $('#menu-dashboard').pointer({
        content: '<?php echo $pointer_content; ?>',
        position: 'top',
        close: function() {
            // This function is fired when you click the close button
        }
      }).pointer('open');
   });
   //]]>
   </script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is always a way, as shown by some plugins utilizing these pointers, but they are currently meant as an internal core feature and thus have no real API for use.